# error servlet deployment with Wildfly

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, wildfly

During deployment I'm getting the following errors. I use wildfly 8.x.
When it loads the server i get 404 error page.

```
    04:39:07,010 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-11) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectTeam2v2.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectTeam2v2.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1904) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) [rt.jar:1.8.0_73]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) [rt.jar:1.8.0_73]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.8.0_73]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS017354: Could not find the port number listening for protocol javax.ws.rs.core.Application
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.createServletConfig(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:648)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.deployment.UndertowDeploymentInfoService.start(UndertowDeploymentInfoService.java:256)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1948) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1881) [jboss-msc-1.2.2.Final.jar:1.2.2.Final]
    ... 3 more
```

+

```
04:39:14,333 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (Controller Boot Thread) JBAS014613: Operation ("deploy") failed - address: ([("deployment" => "projectTeam2v2.war")]) - failure description: {"JBAS014671: Failed services" => {"jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectTeam2v2.UndertowDeploymentInfoService" => "org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectTeam2v2.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: Failed to start service
    Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: JBAS017354: Could not find the port number listening for protocol javax.ws.rs.core.Application"}}
```

+

```
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectTeam2v2.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectTeam2v2.UndertowDeploymentInfoService: Failed to start service
```

+

```
JBAS014775:    New missing/unsatisfied dependencies:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."projectTeam2v2.war".component."com.ibm.controller.CDController".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectTeam2v2, service jboss.deployment.unit."projectTeam2v2.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."projectTeam2v2.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectTeam2v2, service jboss.deployment.unit."projectTeam2v2.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."projectTeam2v2.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectTeam2v2, service jboss.deployment.unit."projectTeam2v2.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.deployment.unit."projectTeam2v2.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."projectTeam2v2.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectTeam2v2 (missing) dependents: [service jboss.deployment.unit."projectTeam2v2.war".deploymentCompleteService] 
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectTeam2v2.UndertowDeploymentInfoService (missing) dependents: [service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectTeam2v2] 
JBAS014777:   Services which failed to start:      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectTeam2v2.UndertowDeploymentInfoService
```

+

```
JBAS014776:    Newly corrected services:
      service jboss.deployment.unit."projectTeam2v2.war".component."com.ibm.controller.CDController".START (no longer required)
      service jboss.deployment.unit."projectTeam2v2.war".component."com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener".START (no longer required)
      service jboss.deployment.unit."projectTeam2v2.war".component."javax.faces.webapp.FacetTag".START (no longer required)
      service jboss.deployment.unit."projectTeam2v2.war".component."javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.tlv.ScriptFreeTLV".START (no longer required)
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectTeam2v2 (no longer required)
      service jboss.undertow.deployment.default-server.default-host./projectTeam2v2.UndertowDeploymentInfoService (no longer required)
```

+

```
04:46:20,148 ERROR [stderr] (xnio-file-watcher[Watcher for C:\Users\IMC\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\deployments\SpringMVC.war/]-0) Exception in thread "xnio-file-watcher[Watcher for C:\Users\IMC\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\deployments\SpringMVC.war/]-0" java.nio.file.ClosedWatchServiceException

04:46:20,149 ERROR [stderr] (xnio-file-watcher[Watcher for C:\Users\IMC\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\deployments\SpringMVC.war/]-0)   at sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchService.checkOpen(AbstractWatchService.java:80)

04:46:20,149 ERROR [stderr] (xnio-file-watcher[Watcher for C:\Users\IMC\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\deployments\SpringMVC.war/]-0)   at sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchService.checkKey(AbstractWatchService.java:92)

04:46:20,149 ERROR [stderr] (xnio-file-watcher[Watcher for C:\Users\IMC\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\deployments\SpringMVC.war/]-0)   at sun.nio.fs.AbstractWatchService.take(AbstractWatchService.java:119)

04:46:20,149 ERROR [stderr] (xnio-file-watcher[Watcher for C:\Users\IMC\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\deployments\SpringMVC.war/]-0)   at org.xnio.nio.WatchServiceFileSystemWatcher.run(WatchServiceFileSystemWatcher.java:85)

04:46:20,150 ERROR [stderr] (xnio-file-watcher[Watcher for C:\Users\IMC\wildfly-8.2.1.Final\standalone\deployments\SpringMVC.war/]-0)   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

In the web.xml i don't have mysql dependency. Could this be the problem? 
Thank you for your time :).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i removed web.xml and it works now. can any1 explain me why?

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">
    <display-name>Integration CRUD JSP Project</display-name>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/api/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
        <param-value>lang</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CDController</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.ibm.controller.CDController</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CDController</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/CDController</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

</web-app>
```

this is the web.xml

Comment: You don't have a `<servlet-class/>` defined for the `javax.ws.rs.core.Application`. Try leaving the `<servlet/>` definition for it off and just keep the `<servlet-mapping/>`.

Comment: Thank you very much!
If i configure web.xml like shown here https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24983/configure.htm#RESTF187 (with servlet-class) will be good too?

Comment: You shouldn't need to provide the implementation class at all. FWIW that specific example won't work at all since WIldFly uses RESTEasy and not Jersey for it's JAX-RS implementation. Just remove the `<servlet/>` element and the rest should work.